# The power of galaxy tab 4 7,0 charger

Tags: tablet

Please what is the power of tab 4 7.0 charger

Is it like 1 or 2 Amp

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This question doesn't appear to be about Android specifically, so it may not get answered here.

Answer (score 1):

The charger that came with my tablet is rated at 5V and 1.0 amps.